# First function executing only - of two functions called by .onsubmit of two forms

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two functions in external JS file, each function to be executed on submit of respective form on separate pages. These functions are called from within an initialization function which is itself loaded on window.onload. Only the first function (whichever is placed first) works (thus in example below, totalOrder() for the order.html page functions, the validateForm() for the register.html page does not). I want both to be working for their respective pages.

Excuse the imprecise language, I am VERY new to JavaScript. I suspect I am missing something basic.

```
function totalOrder() {
alert("total order");
}

function validateForm() {
    alert("validation");
}

function init() {
    var orderForm = document.getElementById("order_Form");
    var regForm = document.getElementById("reg_Form");

    regForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    orderForm.onsubmit = totalOrder;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Form in register.html:

```
<form id="reg_Form" method="post" action="#" name="registration">... <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Form in order.html:

```
<form id="order_Form" method="post" action="#" name="order">... <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Works fine if the function is called from the html pages, but this is not ideal, e.g.:

```
<form id="reg_Form" method="post" action="#" name="registration" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Using addEventListener instead of onsubmit suffers the same issue, e.g.

```
function init() {
var orderForm = document.getElementById("order_Form");
var regForm = document.getElementById("reg_Form");

orderForm.addEventListener("submit", totalOrder);
regForm.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two pages which each only have one of the forms, but you try to modify both forms in the javascript. You could use something like this:

```
function init() {
    var orderForm = document.getElementById("order_Form");
    var regForm = document.getElementById("reg_Form");

    if (regForm != null) regForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    if (orderForm != null) orderForm.onsubmit = totalOrder;
}
```

That way you only try to modify the form which actually exists on the page that's using the JS code.